# Extract content of a HTML-file

Tags: python, html

I've got a HTML-file which looks like this (simplified):

```
<table class="main" frame="box" rules="all" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="table-layout:fixed; width:325.68pt; height:528.96pt;">
Here is some text.
<table class="main" frame="box" rules="all" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style=" width:50.88pt; height:77.28pt;">
Here is another text which ends right here.
</table>
Here are also some words...
</table>
```

What I'd like to extract is the content of "table class="main"", so in explicit words, I'd like to extract the same as it is written above to a file. Consider: The example is simplified; around the -tags, there are many others...
I tried to extract the content using the following code:

```
root = lxml.html.parse('www.test.xyz').getroot()

for empty in root.xpath('//*[self::b or self::i][not(node())]'):
    empty.getparent().remove(empty)

tables = root.cssselect('table.main')
```

The above code works. But the problem is that I got a part twice; see what I mean: The result of the code is:

```
<table class="main" frame="box" rules="all" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="table-layout:fixed; width:325.68pt; height:528.96pt;">
Here is some text.
<table class="main" frame="box" rules="all" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style=" width:50.88pt; height:77.28pt;">
Here is another text which ends right here.
</table>
Here are also some words...
</table>
<table class="main" frame="box" rules="all" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style=" width:50.88pt; height:77.28pt;">
Here is another text which ends right here.
</table>
```

So the problem is that the middle part appears one time too much at the end.
Why is this and how can this be omitted and fixed?

paul t., also a stackoverflow-user, told me to use "root.xpath('//table[@class="main" and not(.//table[@class="main"])]')". This code prints out exactly the part I have twice.

I hope the problem is described clearly enough...thanks for any help and any propositions :)

Comment: You realise you have two tables with class="main" in the code, right?

Comment: Yes, that's the point. Is there any way to handle this?

Comment: which one do you want to get? or both of them?

Comment: Both of them, but I don't want to get one of them twice.

Comment: Do you realize that one of your tables is embedded in the other ? Perhaps you only want to select the outer table: xpath( '//table[not(descendant::table)]' ). If you select both tables and print or serialize them, you will output the outer table with the inner table within it, and then the inner table again. Also the html file seems to be garbled as there is content before and after the html tags. ( I removed the before and after junk before trying to parse it. )

Comment: Could you edit the HTML sample down to a simple, self-contained, correct, representative, **short** minimal example, pretty please?

Comment: You could improve this question a lot by removing the gigantic HTML file entirely -- it looks to me like your snippets show just what the problem is.

Comment: I updated the question and the content :) Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to select all the tables with class "main" which are not already selected as descendants of the same elements.
This seems to work fine:

```
root.xpath('//table[@class="main" and not(ancestor::table[@class="main"])]')
```